# Is there a name for a violin with five strings?

Tags: terminology, string-instruments, violin-family

Is there a distinguishing name for this stringed instrument that is, as best as I an find, otherwise referred to as a "five-string violin?"

[image: "violin" with five strings]

Comment: I don't think there is a special name. The five-string cello typically used fo Bach's solo suite #6 is also still called cello.

Comment: 5-string bass = 5-string bass. 6-string bass = 6 string bass. 7-string guitar = 7 string guitar, They're pretty accurate terms. Although tunings may vary. As in 5-string bass, low B. Maybe the tuning, if not ony one tuning, is an important factor in naming, as well.

Comment: Agreed with other comments.  No special name seems to have emerged as yet, although the c-g-d'-a'-e'' violin/viola is a not uncommon instrument nowadays.  My apprentice built one as her master instrument.

Comment: [A sacrilegious one.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BvsvaCU6i1M)

Answer (score 9):

They are simply called ["five-string violins"](https://www.violinist.com/blog/tartini/200810/9235/) in the English language, and usually combine the viola and the violin's ranges.

Other stringed instruments that have 5 strings are generally of the viol family, e.g. the *[pardessus de viole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardessus_de_viole)* which could have 5 or 6 strings, or the *[quinton](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinton_(instrument))* which specifically has 5 strings.

Comment: So is it correct that *quinton* is a name specific to this instrument, but it has not been accepted into English (from French)?

Comment: @feetwet After reading a translated version of the french wikipedia page, it looks to me like rather different instrument. The tuning has thirds in it instead of straight fifths, and often has frets.

Comment: @feetwet The quinton is traditionally considered a member of the viol family; it is not a violin. However, [there is some debate](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3518969) about how many violin characteristics it absorbed. Nonetheless, it is not the five-string violin.

Comment: It might be mentioned that treble violas da gamba often had five strings (instead ot the more usual six nowadays).  They sound better as a rule because there's less pressure on the belly.